# Biblatex / list of references by same authors

Tags: biblatex

As expected, biblatex substitutes a dash to the name of the author after the first reference in a list. But it repeats the name if the, say, second reference of the list falls in a new page. I cannot reproduce this in a MWE, sorry, but it happens in my bibliography. Any way to force the dash even after a page break?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{gordon2004,
  title = {Continental divide: {{Ernst Cassirer}} and {{Martin Heidegger}} at {{Davos}}, 1929 -- an allegory of intellectual history},
  author = {Gordon, Peter E.},
  date = {2004},
  journaltitle = {Modern Intellectual History},
  shortjournal = {Modern Intellectual History},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {219--248},
  publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
  issn = {1479-2451}
}
@article{gordon2005,
  title = {Myth and modernity: {{Cassirer}}'s critique of {{Heidegger}}},
  author = {Gordon, Peter E.},
  date = {2005},
  journaltitle = {New German Critique},
  number = {94},
  pages = {127--168}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, maxbibnames=2, minbibnames=1, maxsortnames=2, scauthorsbib=false, doi=false, isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, citepages=suppress]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{gordon2004} e \cite{gordon2005}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact I realize the substitution sometimes happens even across pages but it is erratic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no erratic behaviour here. With your setting `pagetracker=true,` is active, which tracks all pages separately in onesided mode and tracks double pages (spreads) together in twosided mode (which is active in the MWE thanks to the `book` class). That means that you get no dash if the entry starts at the top of a left page, but you do get a dash at the top of a right page (because it is on the same spread).

If you don't want `biblatex` to take into account pages here, remove the test from the relevant macro.

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=philosophy-verbose,
  maxbibnames=2, minbibnames=1, maxsortnames=2,
  scauthorsbib=false,
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, eprint=false,
  citepages=suppress,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibnote{filler}{A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[prenote=filler]
\end{document}
```

[image: Dash on top of page.]

Comment: It works but you point me to a reasonable approach of repeating the name if the second citation is on an odd page, considering the first citation is not under the eyes of the reader... Thanks!